# HaProxy configuration to atmosphere - WebSockets

Tags: websocket, haproxy, atmosphere

I am using two Tomcat webserver in different server with clustering. And both the server configured in HA-Proxy. So i deployed my application in both the servers. In my application am using atmosphere(WebSocket). So i need to configure this atmosphere in haproxy as well so please help me to do so #thanks

Issue is i am accessing my application in two systems. now pushing is happening in only one server. it should push both the servers. but its not happening....

Comment: This site is for programming questions. Server/network configuration is off-topic.

Comment: Is your issue something where push only reach connections suspended by the server where the event is triggered? I mean if connections are suspended on server B, they never receive messages pushed from server A?

Comment: @Guillame no ... both Server A and Server B is up. For eg: server A is broadcasting it is reflecting in UI(client) but not in the another client because it may pointing to Server B. Both server A and B is in HA so it should push to both the client.. its not happening ...

Answer (score 1):

Normally with a proxy web service, you push a request from the client to the proxy, it then pushes to a server in the pool, which replies to the proxy, which will send the reply back to the original client.  Normally, the proxy then maintains a connection history list, so that subsequent connection from the same client, end up at the same server.

The important bit, is that with a proxy, the conversation between client and proxy, and between proxy and server are separate, but the proxy understands the application layer enough to make the client think it's the server.

If you want to use a direct websocket connection between client and server, then presumably you're not using an application layer that a conventional proxy will understand, hence you'll struggle with an out-of-the-box proxy server, like haproxy, as most examples will involve a http connection.  However haproxy can do non-http proxying. http://www.linickx.com/load-balance-anything-with-haproxy

That said, Marc B is probably right, and this should be a discussion on serverfault.com, as the programmatic solution, of adding code to the server application, to connect back to the client, is probably the wrong one, as I presume they'll be using a browser, and not a client you have control over.

Comment: thanks for your reply. Any configuration we need to change in ha-proxy to make load ban-lancer to push in both the client ???

Comment: Theoretically there is no reason why the proxy couldn't proxy a connection back to the client, especially as the server could probably tell the proxy the client's address.  That said, you're talking application layer stuff (OSI model), and unless the proxy server understands your application layer, it's not going to be able to do it (unless you can find an application layer that does what you want that a proxy might understand, SOCKS maybe?)